# Python Output Ambiguity

Tags: python, output, newline, ambiguity

So I have written the following code to generate [combinations (n choose k)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

combinations = []
used = []

def init(num):
    for i in range(0, num+1):
        combinations.append(0)
        used.append(0)

def printSolution(coef):
    for i in range(1, coef+1):
        print(combinations[i], " ", end=' ')
    print("\n")

def generateCombinations(which, what, num, coef):
    combinations[which] = what
    used[what] = 1

    if which == coef:
        printSolution(coef)
    else:
        for next in range(what+1, num+1):
            if not used[next]:
                generateCombinations(which+1, next, num, coef)

    used[what] = 0

n = int(input("Give n:"))
k = int(input("Give k:"))

if k <= n:
    init(n)
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        generateCombinations(1, i, n, k)

input()
```

The problem with it is that when it outputs the text, instead of writing one line after another like this:

```
Give n:4
Give k:3
1 2 3
1 2 4
1 3 4
2 3 4
```

It actually outputs it like this:

```
Give n:4
Give k:3
1 2 3

1 2 4

1 3 4

2 3 4
```

My question is, why does that actually happen, and how to fix it? I must say that I'm new to python, so don't be harsh on me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print("\n")
```

Prints a newline, and ends it with a newline. Thus two newlines

Two options to remove one of them:

```
print()
```

or

```
print("\n", end="")
```